# Need Help! How to select specific polygon to draw on google map using it's API. data from fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am learning and trying to use google map api to draw a select area from data in fusion table. it is data for province in thailand that i import from KML to  fusion table.
by using following code.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 13.7248936, lng: 100.4930264 },
        zoom: 6
      })
      var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        name: 'fsru',
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: '1aclHzWdYrUCcHHfgbmKnFTqTTppgeI0SkKNXPpYR'
        },
        styles: [{
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#ff0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.3
          }
        }, {
          where: 'project = name',
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#0000FF',
            fillOpacity: 1
          }
        }]
      })
      layer.setMap(map)
```

and this is fusion table.

https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1aclHzWdYrUCcHHfgbmKnFTqTTppgeI0SkKNXPpYR&fbclid=IwAR3VQLH51ONsnLm8v0KcWhk6MdcDFSeDvig3t1-tYoJ90-IqIm_XRJBLgzA#rows:id=1

what my condition is i want to draw a shape,polygon from geometry in the fusion by select name of province to draw. but by this code all polygon is show up even though i select only province name.

i have a problem that

when i use

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            name: 'fsru',
            query: {
              select: 'geometry' and 'name',
              from: '1aclHzWdYrUCcHHfgbmKnFTqTTppgeI0SkKNXPpYR'
              where: 'name' like krabi
            },
```

it does not work.

i want to select only specific area to render but it not working.

Comment: there is no value "name" in the project column.  where: "project = 1" works for me ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xa90euh2/))

Comment: hi geocodezip,  thank you. but what if i want to show only select area without render other area what should i do?


      var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        name: 'fsru',
        query: {
          select: 'geometry',
          from: '1aclHzWdYrUCcHHfgbmKnFTqTTppgeI0SkKNXPpYR'
        }


can i modified above code with the select name, geometry  from fusiontable where name ='xxxxx'   is there any query code i have to use?

Comment: Please edit your question with **the minimum, complete and necessary code** allowing to reproduce the issue and a **clear statement** of what you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work. Please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i edited some more. is it clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause syntax is the issue.

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.16,99),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: '1aclHzWdYrUCcHHfgbmKnFTqTTppgeI0SkKNXPpYR',
            where: "'name' like 'Krabi'",
        },
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: '#9acd32',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 0
            }
        }],
        map: map
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```